# Sort mapbox studio poi icons according to data field

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm editing the poi_labels in a mapbox studio style. I'd like the places that use a maki cafe icon to be favored when there are collisions so that if there is a cafe icon and a restaurant icon that would overlap, the cafe icon is the one that gets rendered. You're clearly supposed to use the "Sort key" option under the "Placement" tab, but I can't figure out how to make this work despite having tried several formulas and approaches. I understand that the lowest numbers are favored, so I tried setting it up where a 1 is returned for maki cafe icons, and a 2 is returned for all other icons (see screenshot below). I thought it would be best to do this by editing the style, but it's also ok if it's an at-runtime solution. This is for a web-app using mapbox-gl js.

UPDATE: As the approved answer points out, this setup works. The issue I was actually having here seems to be that, regardless of their display priority, cafes do not appear on the map at zoom levels below 16. I'm not sure how to change that or if you even can, but that's a separate issue.

[image]

Comment: You have described your approach, but you haven't shown what the result is. Also, this isn't really a StackOverflow question if it doesn't have code in it. Best to set up a codepen with your progress so far.

Comment: @SteveBennett nothing I've tried has any effect and I don't see how I would set up a codepen for Mapbox Studio.

Comment: Mapbox Studio is (mostly) just a front end for editing style files. So you can make a codepen with an embedded style file, with just the specific layer of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your Expression works.Please see cafe_s.png (enables your expression) and default_s.png. Caffe overcomes other POI icons.

Also if the case is Cafe or not, then candidate.png setting is fine. I also attach Expression here.

```
[
  "case",
  [
    "==",
    ["get", "maki"],
    "cafe"
  ],
  1,
  2
]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Interesting, this clearly seems to work for you! This isn't the behavior I am seeing in my test. The only difference in what I was looking at was that the other icons that still take precedence over cafe icons are restaurant icons. Also your equation format is useful.